# GDB Skips While Loop Condition When Used With File Input

Tags: c++, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, getline

Alright Stack Overflow, I am running into a decently persistent problem in my C++ code. I'm sure this is one of those dumb mistake moments, but I have tried everything and cannot seem to squish this bug.

I have a bit of code here, and it's behavior is very odd. I have a main function that opens a file containing text I want to read in. I was taught in programming fundamentals class at my university that I could use getline() as a condition for the while loop, which is nice since it automatically terminates when it reaches the end of the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream input_mem_traces("gcc.txt");
    string trace_to_parse = "";
    
        while(getline(input_mem_traces, trace_to_parse))
        {
            cout << trace_to_parse << endl;
        }

}
```

When I compile and run it, it works just fine. It reads out every single line of the file I pass it, and returns with no problems.

However, when I try to use gdb, and set a breakpoint at the line

`cout << trace_to_parse << endl;`

it didn't hit the breakpoint. Curious as to why that was, I broke above the loop, and tried single stepping through the code. When I got to the while loop, and tried to step, it simply skipped to the line after it, which happened to be the end of the program.

This behavior occurs both using the VSCode GUI front end for gdb, as well as straight gdb from the command line. I am running this on Windows using Ubuntu under WSL2, and VSCode as my IDE with the Remote - WSL extension enabled.

Comment: The most obvious answer is the file was not opened. Is your working directory different when running in gdb?

Comment: No, the working directory doesn't change, and the file is present with the correct name.

Comment: To prove that use an absolute path to the file and see if the behavior differs.

Comment: That did it. Wow. Ok. I pulled this error out of a project I was working on. I'm going to try this there and see if it helps. If I need help there I'll open a new question if appropriate. The help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was some weirdness going on with the working directory with GDB. For some reason, my working directory was changing under the VSCode GUI, thus the file was not able to be opened, and the while loop condition performed as expected for that circumstance by not entering the loop. Upon the recommendation by Retired Ninja in the comments, I used an absolute path in the fstream object constructor, and that solved the issue.